How to use Encryption in SAP and Store in Database
I have the task to save username and passwords in a SAP table. The password should be stored encrypted (aes128) in the database. Before sending, the password should be decrypted again. Decrypting doesn't work. Does anyone have experience with this?
This is my source code for storing the data:
data : passwd  type string,
       encoded type string,
       decoded type string.


data: lv_plaintext  type xstring.
data: lv_plaintext2 type xstring.
data: lv_key        type xstring.

*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
* Selection-Screen
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*

parameters: p_name type char10.
parameters: p_usern type char10.
parameters: p_pass type text10.
parameters: p_descr type text120.


*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
* At Selection Screen Output
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
at selection-screen output.
  loop at screen.
    if screen-name = 'P_PASS'.
      screen-invisible = 1.
      modify screen.
    endif.
  endloop.

*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
* Start of Selection
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
start-of-selection.

* create message
  data: lr_conv_sec type ref to cl_abap_conv_out_ce .
  data: lr_conv_key type ref to cl_abap_conv_out_ce .

  try.
      call method cl_abap_conv_out_ce=>create
        exporting
          encoding    = 'DEFAULT'
*      endian      =
          replacement = '#'
          ignore_cerr = abap_false
        receiving
          conv        =  lr_conv_sec
          .
    catch cx_parameter_invalid_range .
    catch cx_sy_codepage_converter_init .
  endtry.

  lr_conv_sec->write( p_pass ).

* create key
  try.
      call method cl_abap_conv_out_ce=>create
        exporting
          encoding    = 'DEFAULT'
*      endian      =
          replacement = '#'
          ignore_cerr = abap_false
        receiving
          conv        =  lr_conv_key
          .
    catch cx_parameter_invalid_range .
    catch cx_sy_codepage_converter_init .
  endtry.

  lr_conv_key->write( p_pass ).

  try.
    call method lr_conv_sec->get_buffer
      receiving
        buffer = lv_plaintext.
  endtry.

  try.
    call method lr_conv_key->get_buffer
      receiving
        buffer = lv_key.
  endtry.


  data: lv_message type xstring.

* encrypt using AES256
  call method cl_sec_sxml_writer=>encrypt
    exporting
      plaintext  = lv_plaintext
      key        = lv_key
      algorithm  = cl_sec_sxml_writer=>co_aes128_algorithm
    importing
      ciphertext = lv_message.

  data: ls_pwdstore type /vaps/pwdstore.
  ls_pwdstore-name        = p_name.
  ls_pwdstore-username    = p_usern.
  ls_pwdstore-pwd         = lv_message.
  ls_pwdstore-pwdkey      = lv_key.
  ls_pwdstore-description = p_descr.


  modify /vaps/pwdstore from ls_pwdstore.

  write:/ 'Name', ' : ', ls_pwdstore-name.
  write:/ 'Benutzername', ' : ',  ls_pwdstore-username.
  write:/ 'Passwort', ' : ', ls_pwdstore-pwd.
  write:/ 'PWDKEY', ' : ', ls_pwdstore-pwdkey.

And here is the code for the display:
data : passwd  type string,
       encoded type string,
       decoded type string.

data: lv_plaintext  type xstring.
data: lv_plaintext2 type xstring.
data: lv_key        type xstring.

*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
* Selection-Screen
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*

parameters: p_name type char10.


*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
* At Selection Screen Output
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
at selection-screen output.

*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
* Start of Selection
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
start-of-selection.

  data: lv_message type xstring.
  data: ls_pwdstore type /vaps/pwdstore.

  data: lv_length type i,
        e_string type string,
         lt_binary type standard table of x255.


  select single * from /vaps/pwdstore into ls_pwdstore
    where name = p_name.

  lv_key = ls_pwdstore-pwdkey.
  lv_message = ls_pwdstore-pwd.

  call method cl_sec_sxml_writer=>decrypt
    exporting
      ciphertext = lv_message
      key        = lv_key
      algorithm  = cl_sec_sxml_writer=>co_aes128_algorithm
    importing
      plaintext  = lv_plaintext2.



  call function 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
    exporting
      buffer        = lv_plaintext2
    importing
      output_length = lv_length
    tables
      binary_tab    = lt_binary.

  call function 'SCMS_BINARY_TO_STRING'
    exporting
      input_length = lv_length
    importing
      text_buffer  = e_string
    tables
      binary_tab   = lt_binary
    exceptions
      failed       = 1
      others       = 2.
  if sy-subrc <> 0.
*     Implement suitable error handling here
  endif.

  write:/ 'Name', ' : ', p_name.
  write:/ 'PWD', ' : ', e_string.

The table columns PWD and PWDKEY are defined as RWASTRING.


I have to ask, why are you doing this? There is almost certainly a better way than building your own password encryption.

This question is similar to: ABAP Secure Storage: how to store passwords?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I created sample code and it looks working. Maybe you can check your db routine, maybe you lost some data during db oprerations.
REPORT zmky_enc_dec.
DATA: lv_key        TYPE xstring,
      lv_plaintext  TYPE xstring,
      lv_plaintext2 TYPE xstring,
      lv_message    TYPE xstring,
      lv_length     TYPE i,
      e_string      TYPE string,
      lv_ciphertext TYPE xstring.

DATA:  lt_binary TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF x255.

lv_plaintext = '646570'.
lv_key = '5A1F47FE14F72'.

* encription

* encrypt using AES256
CALL METHOD cl_sec_sxml_writer=>encrypt
  EXPORTING
    plaintext  = lv_plaintext
    key        = lv_key
    algorithm  = cl_sec_sxml_writer=>co_aes128_algorithm
  IMPORTING
    ciphertext = lv_ciphertext.

* decription
lv_ciphertext = 'D8B7F50D13B58F8C0B9B50A59891ED2F1C368D6F2DB97A789BDAC131EE346CE8'.
CALL METHOD cl_sec_sxml_writer=>decrypt
  EXPORTING
    ciphertext = lv_ciphertext
    key        = lv_key
    algorithm  = cl_sec_sxml_writer=>co_aes128_algorithm
  IMPORTING
    plaintext  = lv_plaintext2.

CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
  EXPORTING
    buffer        = lv_plaintext2
  IMPORTING
    output_length = lv_length
  TABLES
    binary_tab    = lt_binary.

CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_BINARY_TO_STRING'
  EXPORTING
    input_length = lv_length
  IMPORTING
    text_buffer  = e_string
  TABLES
    binary_tab   = lt_binary
  EXCEPTIONS
    failed       = 1
    OTHERS       = 2.

WRITE:/ 'PWD', ' : ', e_string.

Separated report:
REPORT zmky_enc.
DATA: lv_key        TYPE xstring,
      lv_plaintext  TYPE xstring,
      lv_ciphertext TYPE xstring.

lv_plaintext = '6D6B79736F6674'.
lv_key = '5A1F47FE14F72'.

* encrypt using AES256
CALL METHOD cl_sec_sxml_writer=>encrypt
  EXPORTING
    plaintext  = lv_plaintext
    key        = lv_key
    algorithm  = cl_sec_sxml_writer=>co_aes128_algorithm
  IMPORTING
    ciphertext = lv_ciphertext.

WRITE:/ 'Encrypt', ' : ', lv_ciphertext.

Decryption
REPORT zmky_dec.
DATA: lv_key        TYPE xstring,
      lv_plaintext  TYPE xstring,
      lv_text       TYPE string,
      lv_length     TYPE i,
      lv_ciphertext TYPE xstring.

DATA:  lt_binary TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF x255.

lv_key = '5A1F47FE14F72'.

lv_ciphertext = 'D9276417EA8C93AE373CE24272BD68974C524CC6E34AB2D9496162F5E1CEB2B8'.
CALL METHOD cl_sec_sxml_writer=>decrypt
  EXPORTING
    ciphertext = lv_ciphertext
    key        = lv_key
    algorithm  = cl_sec_sxml_writer=>co_aes128_algorithm
  IMPORTING
    plaintext  = lv_plaintext.

CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
  EXPORTING
    buffer        = lv_plaintext
  IMPORTING
    output_length = lv_length
  TABLES
    binary_tab    = lt_binary.

CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_BINARY_TO_STRING'
  EXPORTING
    input_length = lv_length
  IMPORTING
    text_buffer  = lv_text
  TABLES
    binary_tab   = lt_binary
  EXCEPTIONS
    failed       = 1
    OTHERS       = 2.

WRITE:/ 'Decrypted', ' : ', lv_text.


thanks, but if i split the code in two different Reports it dose not work.

I tried it again in separated report, still working.

This code Works:


data : passwd  type string,
       lv_msg  type string,
       lv_skey type string.

data: lv_pass    type xstring.
data: lv_key     type xstring.
data: lv_message type xstring.

*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*Selection-Screen
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*

parameters: p_name type char10.
parameters: p_usern type char10.
parameters: p_pass type text10.
parameters: p_descr type text120.


*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*At Selection Screen Output
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
at selection-screen output.
  loop at screen.
    if screen-name = 'P_PASS'.
      screen-invisible = 1.
      modify screen.
    endif.
  endloop.

*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*Start of Selection
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
start-of-selection.

  lv_key = cl_sec_sxml_writer=>generate_key( algorithm = cl_sec_sxml_writer=>co_aes128_algorithm  ).

  "Converting the data - From string format to xstring. You can use any other method
  "or function module which converts the string to xstring format
  passwd = p_pass.

  call function 'SCMS_STRING_TO_XSTRING'
    exporting
      text           = passwd
*   MIMETYPE       = ' '
*   ENCODING       =
   importing
     buffer         = lv_pass
   exceptions
     failed         = 1
     others         = 2
            .
  if sy-subrc <> 0.
* MESSAGE ID SY-MSGID TYPE SY-MSGTY NUMBER SY-MSGNO
*         WITH SY-MSGV1 SY-MSGV2 SY-MSGV3 SY-MSGV4.
  endif.


* encrypt using AES256
  call method cl_sec_sxml_writer=>encrypt
    exporting
      plaintext  = lv_pass
      key        = lv_key
      algorithm  = cl_sec_sxml_writer=>co_aes128_algorithm
    importing
      ciphertext = lv_message.

  lv_msg = lv_message.
  lv_skey = lv_key.

  data: ls_pwdstore type /vaps/pwdstore.
  ls_pwdstore-name        = p_name.
  ls_pwdstore-username    = p_usern.
  ls_pwdstore-pwd         = lv_msg.
  ls_pwdstore-pwdkey      = lv_skey.
  ls_pwdstore-description = p_descr.


  modify /vaps/pwdstore from ls_pwdstore.

  write:/ 'Name', ' : ', ls_pwdstore-name.
  write:/ 'Benutzername', ' : ',  ls_pwdstore-username.
  write:/ 'Passwort', ' : ', ls_pwdstore-pwd.
  write:/ 'PWDKEY', ' : ', ls_pwdstore-pwdkey.



An this ist the Method for Decryption.


*Parameters:
*VALUE( ENCRY_DATA )    TYPE /VAPS/PWDSTORE PWD Store
*VALUE( PWD )   TYPE ACO_STRING String


method decrypt_data.

  data: lv_plaintext type xstring.
  data: lv_key       type xstring.
  data: lv_pwd       type xstring.

  data: lv_length type i,
        e_string  type string,
        lt_binary type standard table of x255.

  lv_key = encry_data-pwdkey.
  lv_pwd = encry_data-pwd.

  if lv_pwd is not initial.
    try.
        call method cl_sec_sxml_writer=>decrypt
          exporting
            ciphertext = lv_pwd
            key        = lv_key
            algorithm  = cl_sec_sxml_writer=>co_aes128_algorithm
          importing
            plaintext  = lv_plaintext.
      catch  cx_sy_no_handler.

    endtry.

  endif.




  call function 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
    exporting
      buffer        = lv_plaintext
    importing
      output_length = lv_length
    tables
      binary_tab    = lt_binary.


  "Binary to string
  call function 'SCMS_BINARY_TO_STRING'
    exporting
      input_length = lv_length
    importing
      text_buffer  = e_string
    tables
      binary_tab   = lt_binary
    exceptions
      failed       = 1
      others       = 2.

  pwd = e_string.

endmethod.



